# SQl Server - 2 equal columns with different values

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

```
ID  | Status   | Date  
----+----------+--------------
1   |    1     |   01-01-2017    
2   |    1     |   26-04-2016   
2   |    4     |   20-10-2016  
3   |    1     |   05-11-2015  
3   |    2     |   20-03-2016  
4   |    4     |   06-06-2015  
5   |    1     |   10-04-2017  
5   |    3     |   21-12-2016  
5   |    2     |   25-02-2013  
5   |    4     |   11-03-2014
```

The result that I want is:

```
ID  |  Status1 |  Status2 | Status3  |  Status4 |  Date  
----+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------
1   |    1     |          |          |          |  01 01 2017  
2   |    1     |          |          |          |  26 04 2016   
2   |          |          |          |    4     |  20 10 2016  
3   |    1     |          |          |          |  05 11 2015  
3   |          |    2     |          |          |  20 03 2016  
4   |          |          |          |    4     |  06 06 2015  
5   |    1     |          |          |          |  10 04 2017  
5   |          |          |    3     |          |  21 12 2016  
5   |          |    2     |          |          |  25 02 2013  
5   |          |          |          |    4     |  11 03 2014
```

How can I do the query?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, ***please*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a `CASE` statement. Please note I renamed date to sdate because date is a [reserved word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql).

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (id INT, status INT, [sdate] date)

INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (1, 1, '01-01-2017')
                           ,(2, 1, '04-26-2017')
                           ,(2, 4, '10-20-2016')


    SELECT id
           ,CASE WHEN status = 1 then status else NULL end as status1
           ,CASE WHEN status = 2 then status else NULL end as status2
           ,CASE WHEN status = 3 then status else NULL end as status3
           ,CASE WHEN status = 4 then status else NULL end as status4
           ,sdate
    FROM myTable
```

Comment: A temporary/permanent table is not required for this, if we use a Group By. See my answer.

Comment: @WhirlMind Sorry I'm not sure what you mean? Are you referring to the `CREATE` table statement? It is for the user(s) to try on sqlfiddle or rextester.

Comment: @WhirlMind In addition I don't see why you need a `GROUP BY` or any aggregation?

Comment: Oops, you are right, yes I see my error now. Deleted my answer.